# How to add phonegap bluetooth plugin

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth

I have added Bluetooth plugin using CLI and I added below code to index.html. But this is not working. I am new to phonegap. Please help to include this plugin. I have used the tanelign-bluetooth plugin.

```
<script>
        window.bluetooth.pair(
        function() {   
           alert('Pairing Successful');  
        },
        function(err) {
           alert('There was an error Pairing to a device'+ JSON.stringify(err));  
        }, deviceaddress);
```

Comment: Please post your `config.xml`. Also in your original question, please add the platform your are building on (window, osx, linux), please state your target platform (Android, iOS, windows, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add this first on the device ready event:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);

function yourCallbackFunction(){
    window.bluetooth = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/bluetooth");
}
```

And add this js in your page:
https://github.com/tanelih/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin/tree/master/www

Like this: `<script src="bluetooth.js"></script>`

Documentation: https://github.com/tanelih/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin